# Backspace inserts "^?" in vim

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, linux

I'm using vim editor in linux and every time I type backspace it inserts a "^?" instead. I DID edit the .vimrc file to include `backspace=indent,eol,star` but it did not help. I also tried `backspace=2` and it doesn't work either. The strangest thing is that if I type `:fixdel` it stops inserting the weird `^?` but instead deletes the **next** character instead of the previous.

Comment: `star` is not a valid option for `backspace`; I think you mean `start`.

Answer (score 2):

In `:h fixdel` it mentions this:

```
If the backspace key terminal code is wrong you can use this: >
            :if &term == "termname"
            :  set t_kb=^V<BS>
            :  fixdel
            :endif
Where "^V" is CTRL-V and "<BS>" is the backspace key
        (don't type four characters!).  Replace "termname"
        with your terminal name.
```

Have you tried that in your `vimrc`?

Comment: There's a deeper issue of `TERM` being wrong, and / or `termcap` / `terminfo` having a different idea of `kb` / `kbs` than what the keyboard actually produces.  An ever-green problem in some Linux-shaped corners of the land. :)